# How to set SQLDebug in Xcode 4.2 to show CoreData queries?

Tags: ios, core-data

Does anyone know where or how to set SQLDebug in Xcode 4.2 so that I can see the queries for CoreData.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass the following as an argument to the application:

`-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 1`

Edit your Scheme, add it in "Arguments Passed On Launch"